Error Loading a thumbnail for a video using Coil jetpack compose kotlin
I was trying to generate a thumbnail for a video. The video is from a link on the Internet. Here's the code I'm using to generate the thumbnail:
import coil.ImageLoader
import coil3.video.VideoFrameDecoder

val videoEnabledLoader =
    ImageLoader.Builder(context).components {
        add(VideoFrameDecoder.Factory())
    }.build()

But it gives me this error:

None of the  following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

It specifically points on the add function
Here's the dependencies I am using:
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.5.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-video:3.0.3")


Just to rule out the obvious, did you invalidate caches in Android Studio and did a clean rebuild?

You are mixing incompatible Coil versions.
For the ImageLoader.Builder you use Coil 2.5.0, for the VideoFrameDecoder.Factory you use 3.0.3. The reason for the compile error is that the add function requires a
coil.decode.Decoder.Factory

but you provide a
coil3.decode.Decoder.Factory

That doesn't work.
You need to fix your gradle dependencies to use the same version for all Coil artifacts. Either downgrade to 2.5.0:
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.5.0")
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-video:2.5.0")

and use
import coil.ImageLoader
import coil.decode.VideoFrameDecoder

or upgrade to 3.0.3:
implementation("io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-compose:3.0.3")
implementation("io.coil-kt.coil3:coil-video:3.0.3")

and use
import coil3.ImageLoader
import coil3.video.VideoFrameDecoder

You should probably use a variable for the Coil version and use it in the gradle dependency to mitigate the risk of version mismatches in the future, or - better yet - migrate to version catalogs.

tyg post some sample code of the suggested solution thanks

I added an example of how the factory could look like.

VideoFrameDecoder.Factory() is from Coil not my own

Ah, I see; sorry, never worked with coil-video before. Now, after adding that dependency and importing import coil.decode.VideoFrameDecoder the code from your sample works without any issues. Please verify you use the imports from my answer and the one above. If that doesn't work please edit your question and provide a list of all coil artifacts you use in your gradle files, including their version numbers.

It didn't work I'm updating the Question

It rejected your imports

I rewrote the answer in light of the new information provided.

The error is gone however the thumbnail loads as a black screen is yours displaying a proper thumbnail ? If so please share the code thanks

That depends on the video used and is unrelated to this question. Better ask a new one while also providing a [mre].

I'm not so experienced with writing on stack overflow it has so many formatting rules but  I can add the entire code that's left in the Question if that helps I loaded another video and it works perfectly as intended. Thanks tyg

Well, it needs to be another question. Don't fuss too much about the formatting though, just try to do it right and when it still falls short someone else will come along and edit the question for you, until you get the hang of it. The important part is that the code you provide in the new question suffices as a [mre]. Make sure everything that is needed to reproduce the issue is there while also removing everything that is not necessary to reproduce the issue.
